# Add data loading message in fusion chart Angular 8

Tags: angular, fusioncharts

How can I display a message before the data is loaded in fusion chart without the use of render function on the component side?

So I have created my charts using the following code:

```
<fusioncharts width="100%" height="600" [type]="metric.type" [dataSource]="metric"> </fusioncharts>
```

Here I pass the chart data as JSON in dataSource, so I don't need render functions on the component side and my charts work fine.

I have read the documentation but couldn't find any way of setting a dataLoadStartMessage someway through the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

In the FusionCharts directive, you can call all the message type parameters for example, when the data is loading you can use dataEmptyMessage attribute, here is a demo snippet

```
<fusioncharts width="100%" height="600" [type]="metric.type" [dataSource]="metric" dataEmptyMessage="Please wait data is loading"> </fusioncharts>
```

Comment: I tried using this but still no loading message is displayed. Instead I sometime see in the top left corner "Fusion chart will render here".

Comment: Check out this sample, where the data is loaded from an external source - https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-md844

To change "Fusion chart will render here" message use placeholder attr in the FusionCharts directive. Shown in the sample

Comment: Following your sample the loading message still does not work on my side. The placeholder attribute works fine and changes the "Fusion chart will render here" message though.

Comment: share a sandbox sample, to investigate it further

Comment: Does the loading message only works when the data is fetched from an api?

Comment: No there are numerous message configurable options for different situations - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/common-use-cases/change-chart-messages

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text and style of the chart status messages that appear throughout the life cycle of the chart

```
var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'column2d',
    dataLoadStartMessage: "Fetching revenue data for the previous year",
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'xmlurl',
    dataSource: 'columndata.php'
});
```

to customise styling of dataLoadStartMessage, the attributes will be:

```
dataLoadStartMessageFont: 'Helvetica',
dataLoadStartMessageFontSize: '24',
dataLoadStartMessageColor: ‘#00FF00'
```

To more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/common-use-cases/change-chart-messages#setting-custom-messages

Here is the demo fiddle - https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=101&layout=left